# Out put clean format of html parse

Tags: php

I am using the below code to retrieve a specific div and its contents, when you view source of my page all the html is formatted nicely, is there anyway to format the html of the below code? ive tried ob_start as well as formatOutput set to true but all the html from it is all jack up in the view source.

```
<?php 

   $doc = new DOMDocument();   
   $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
   $doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
   $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/activity.php?uid=94003');    
   $matches = (new DOMXPath($doc))->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'global1')]");
   foreach ($matches as $node) {
       echo $doc->saveHTML($node);
   }   

?>
```

it currently out puts like this

```
     <div>
<table></table>
        <table></table>
<table></table>
     </div>
```

I'm trying to output it like this

```
<div>
    <table></table>
    <table></table>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? What's wrong? Can you post the actual and expected output?

Comment: Jacked up how? Show us the expected output and what you're currently getting. We're not mind readers (at least not me). If it's just about how the source looks, why does it even matter if the code works?

Comment: all the divs are pushed to one side so the source code is all clean and formatted but this part in not

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I updated it

Comment: HTML TIdy let's you do that: http://www.html-tidy.org/

Comment: I think it's because you're echoing each table separately in the loop. Create a new `DOMDocument` containing the `<div>` with all the `<table>` elements in it, then save that once.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you @Barmar I am new to all this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[htmLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/) could help you

> make HTML markup in text more secure and standard-compliant process
>   text for use in HTML, XHTML or XML documents; HTML5 support restrict
>   HTML elements, attributes or URL protocols using black- or white-lists
>   balance tags, check element nesting, transform deprecated attributes
>   and tags, make relative URLs absolute, etc. fast, highly customizable,
>   well-documented single, 55 kb file simple HTML Tidy alternative free
>   and licensed under LGPL v3 and GPL v2+ use to filter, secure &
>   sanitize HTML in blog comments or forum posts, generate XML-compatible
>   feed items from web-page excerpts, convert HTML to XHTML, pretty-print
>   HTML, scrape web-pages, reduce spam, remove XSS code, etc.

you can achieve it with something like the following code:

```
    <?php
      require("htmLawed/htmLawed.php");

      $doc = new DOMDocument();   
      $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
      $doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
      $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/activity.php?uid=94003');    
      $matches = (new DOMXPath($doc))->query("//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), 'global1')]");

      $result =  "<pre>";
      foreach ($matches as $node) {
            $temp = $doc->saveHTML($node);
            $result .= htmlspecialchars( htmLawed($temp, array('tidy'=>4)));
     } 
     $result .=  "</pre>";
     echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: that just total destroyed it and brought everything from the page and diidnt format it

Comment: @Codi I've updated my answer.check it and inform me about the result.

Comment: it says Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Comment: @Codi convert it to string via `(string)$node`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean convert it to a string I am not to familiar with this

Comment: @Codi I've applied it in my answer. try it again.

Comment: no same error Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in

Comment: @Codi, ok, check it again

Comment: thank you figured it out removed pre and htmlspecial part

Comment: @Codi you're welcome, I'm glad finally you do it.  well done.